# Overwrite existing style with new style

Tags: css

Is there a way or operator in CSS to assign a new style to specific element? I don't want to change original style because it belongs to a plugin and changing it will change it on all my pages. However I want to change the position of the element on a specific web page.

I also can't call those styles in my html because that CSS file is used solely in jquery plugin, you only put `class="slideshow"` in html `div` and thats that. I can change that CSS file to suit my preferences, however I don't know how to change it for specific instances?

Comment: why dont you just make a new class instead ??

Comment: you should CSS specificty in this case.

Comment: And do with it what? Style I need to modify is in a larger file that belongs to a plugin, I don't call those styles directly

Comment: check the code. http://jsbin.com/qivapupa/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a specific styling on a specific instance of your plugin, you should assign a specific class or id to a parent container of that plugin for the instance you need customization.

Example : you can give the `id="special"` to a parent of the plugin in the page you want customization.

Then you can use that selector to style it independently from other instances of that same plugin.

example *CSS*:

```
 #special .slideshow /*other selectors */ {
        /*your specific style */
    }
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @LazyPeon I provided an example, if you want a more specific one, you should provide your code (HTML/CSS) so I can provide it.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario CSS specificity Rule will be helpful for you.

For example in your plugin you are using `RED Font Color` in class `slideshow`. Then in your another CSS file you can create a more specific Rule.

Check the Demo what I've posted above on comments section. Here is the **[direct link.](http://jsbin.com/qivapupa/1/edit)**

```
div.slider .slideshow {color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the element by name:

```
#htmlitemname{
 color: green;
}
```

CSS is cascading, i.e.  it will apply it top down - general, class and then the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **!important** to your css if you wish it to override any inline styles.  So long as you make a style sheet specifically for that page, this should work for what you need.  Hope this helps :)